# calendar datepicker in responsive design

Tags: html

I want to use Jalali calendar datepicker in my website,but it doesn't work in tablets or smartphones because of a meta tag used for responsive design:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

As soon as I remove meta tag it works well, but I need this meta tag for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.It will adjust by itself whenever display size gets reduced:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

If this doesn't work then you can visit below link:

https://github.com/topics/jalali-date-picker