# Calendar datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I want to use Jalali calendar datepicker in my website,but it doesn't work in tablets or smartphones because of a meta tag used for responsive design.As soon as I add this meta tag
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` this does not work

```js
var regional = "en",
  isJalali = false;
$('.datepicker').click(function(e) {
  datepicker(this, {
    single: true,
    isJalali: isJalali,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: "-150y",
    maxDate: $("#AdaultMaxDate").val(),
    yearRangeJalali: "1250:1500",
    yearRangeGregorian: "1900:2030",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.hamsafartour.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.hamsafartour.com/js/datepicke.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.hamsafartour.com/js/jqueryUi.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.hamsafartour.com/css/DatePicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" readonly autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "this does not work"?

Comment: I mean when I clicked the datepicker input , the calendar would not be appeared, but when I remove meta tag the calendar will be shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calendar datepicker in responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54230434/calendar-datepicker-in-responsive-design)

Comment: Actually I have got a lot of pages used this calendar in and I can change it to another calendar. Is there no way to solve the problem by this calendar?